# Error: Expected Expression Before 'struct', when making a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I keep getting an error when trying to make a linked list. The error is "expected expression before 'struct'" on both of the lines where I try to `malloc()` a new node. I've looked at similar questions and tried to fix my code but I can't get it to work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct List {
    int x;
    struct List *next;
};

int main() {
    struct List* head = (struct List*)malloc(sizof(struct List));
    if (head == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    head->x = 1;
    head->next = (struct List*)malloc(sizof(struct List));
    head->next->x = 2;
    head->next->next = NULL;

    struct List* current = head;
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%d", current->x);
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeof` not `sizof`?

Comment: `sizof()` -->> `sizeof()`

Comment: Also, you needn't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in statements like this

```
struct List* head = (struct List*)malloc(sizof(struct List));
                                         ^^^^^
```

There must be

```
struct List* head = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
                                         ^^^^^^
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

And you should free all allocated memory for the list before exiting the program.

Comment: Yep, didn't notice the typo. Thank you!